# How to add unit quaternion constraint only to an object in the plant?

Tags: drake

I have a very simple case: a box on a table
Need to add quaternion constraints on the object. But looking into the documentations, there is the AddUnitQuaternionConstraintOnPlant() constraints which enforces the constraints to all object in the plant.
What I have done:
Declare the object's generalized positions as decision variables

```
q_o_vars = prog.NewContinuousVariables(nq_o, N, "q_o")
```

Then

```
AddUnitQuaternionConstraintOnPlant(plant, q_o_vars[:, i], prog)
```

Then it produces error saying:
`condition 'q_vars.rows() == plant.num_positions()' failed`.

Is there a function already there instead of mannually enforcing it to the object in the plant?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, `AddUnitQuaternionConstraintOnPlant` will add UnitQuaternion constraints to *all* of the quaternion joints in the plant, so it expects the decision variables passed in to represent all of the positions in the plant.

You can also add a [`UnitQuaternionConstraint`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.inverse_kinematics.html?highlight=unitqu#pydrake.multibody.inverse_kinematics.UnitQuaternionConstraint) manually on any 4 decision variables.  It would look something like this:

```
  quat = prog.NewContinuousVariables(4)
  prog.AddConstraint(UnitQuaternionConstraint(), quat)
```